# Logs for an API in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, api, logging, symfony-1.4

I am working on a REST API in Symfony 1.4

I would like to log everything that comes in and out of my "api" application. In a log/api folder, I will keep track of api calls in various files. For a call to myModule/myAction, I will have three files:

- myModule_myAction_RQ.log for all requests
- myModule_myAction_RS.log for all responses
- myModule_myAction_error.log for all error responses

I know how to do that manually, adding some code at the beginning and at the end of each action. Here is how I go:

```
class myActions extends sfActions
{   
/**
 * log function
 */
private static function customLog($message, $seed, $url, $content, $type)
{
    $file =  sprintf('%s/%s_%s.log', sfConfig::get('sf_log_dir', "no_log_dir")."/api", $message, $type);
    $logger = new sfFileLogger(
                new sfEventDispatcher(), 
                array('file'=> $file)
            );

    $logger->log( sprintf("#%s# (%s) %s ", $seed, $url, $content),
                    0, 
                    "info"
    );
}

/**
  * Executes index action
  *
  * @param sfRequest $request A request object
  */
  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    try {           
        $json_msg = $request->getContent();
        // LOG !!!
        $seed = rand();
        $current_uri = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
        self::customLog("availability", $seed, $current_uri, $json_msg, 'RQ');

                    // Do some API logic to set $response_msg
                    // ...

                    $this->response_msg = $response_msg;

        // LOG !!!
        self::customLog("myModule_index", $seed, $current_uri, $response_msg, 'RS');

    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        // throw $e;
        $this->setTemplate("error");
        $this->error = $e;

        // LOG !!!
        self::customLog("myModule_index", $seed, $current_uri, $e->getCode().":".$e->getMessage(), 'error');
    }

  }
```

Here are some example of logged information:

```
 myModule_index_RQ.log:
 Apr 25 11:49:31 symfony [emerg] #958824120# (http://host.local/api_dev.php/users/1/index {"price_km":0.66,"reservation_type":3, "position":{"long":2.139015,"lat":41.37947}} 
 Apr 25 11:56:27 symfony [emerg] #512729287# (http://host.local/api_dev.php/users/1/index {"price_km":0.66,"reservation_type":3,"position":{"long":2.161576,"lat":41.396896}}

myModule_index_RS.log:
Apr 25 11:49:32 symfony [emerg] #958824120# (http://host.local/api_dev.php/users/1/index) {"id_availability":539,"alternatives":[{"id_alternative":1,"duration":9,"reservation_type":3,"distance":3.5,"price":1.62,"original_price":2.31}]} 
Apr 25 11:56:27 symfony [emerg] #512729287# (http://host.local/api_dev.php/users/1/index) {"id_availability":540} 

myModule_index_error.log:
 Apr 25 11:38:20 symfony [emerg] #1059359810# (http://host.local/api_dev.php/users/1/index) 4205:Position to out of service area
```

Now this could quickly get tedious...

I understand that with a good knowledge of Symfony internals, I could achieve this nicely (DRYly). So here come my questions:

- Events may be the way to get it done. Am I right ? If so, which are the events that I should use ? How would I put this together ?
- with $request->getContent(), I am able to get the content of the message that was sent to me. How can I pick up my response content ? (as the content of my view is known only after my action is over, this is not something that can be done "as usual").
- Well, then filters could possibly be the way to achieve all this logging functionnality ?
- Maybe this problem is sooo standard that I could set it up in some config file ? Is it silly ? Or some module may be doing just that ?

This level of Symfony internals are still quite new to me, so any hint, piece of code... will be very welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems filters is the way to do it...
First, I buid up a filter class in the lib folder of the app:

```
<?php
class LogFilter extends sfFilter{

 public function execute($filterChain){

      $request = $this->context->getRequest();
      $response = $this->context->getResponse();

      $seed = rand();
      $this->customLog($seed, $request->getContent(), 'RQ');

      $filterChain->execute($filterChain);    

      $this->customLog($seed, $response->getContent(), 'RS');
  }


/**
 * just log
 *  @param integer $seed: a random number that will be identical across request and response.
 *  @param string $content: the content of the message to be logged
 *  @param type: the type of the message (RQ = request, RS = response)
 */
private function customLog($seed, $content, $type)
{
    // get the current action information
    $moduleName = $this->context->getModuleName();
    $actionName = $this->context->getActionName();
    $message = $moduleName."-".$actionName;
    $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

    $file =  sprintf('%s/%s-%s.log', sfConfig::get('sf_log_dir', "no_log_dir")."/api-in", $message, $type);
    $logger = new sfFileLogger(
                new sfEventDispatcher(), 
                array('file'=> $file)
            );

    $logger->log( sprintf("#%s# (%s) %s ", $seed, $url, $content),
                    0, 
                    "info"
    );
}

}
```

Register your filter in the filters.yml configuration file (in your app config folder), between security and cache:

```
rendering: ~
security:  ~

# insert your own filters here
MyCustomFilter:  
  class: LogFilter

cache:     ~
execution: ~
```

And... This is it !